# Simpleweather.js - icons for forecast items

Tags: jquery, weather

I am successfully presenting weather updates using simpleweather.js and am trying to get forecast icons to appear beside the forecast day.

Using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
  location: 'Melborune, Australia',
  unit: 'c',
  success: function(weather) {
  html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
  html += '<ul><li><i style="color:#000" class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
  html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
  html += '<li>'+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>';

  for(var i=0;i<weather.forecast.length;i++) {
    html += '<p><i style="color:#000" class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i>'+weather.forecast[i].day+': '+weather.forecast[i].high+'</p>';
  }

  $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

I can move  around and it will display the icon for the current temp but I don't know what the icon code is for forecasted days.

I am sorry, I am very new to using API's. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forecast[X].image` returns the full size image url for X day's condition code.Hope this i what you meant mate.. :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.simpleWeather({
        location: 'Melborune, Australia',
        unit: 'c',
        success: function (weather) {
            html = '<h2><i class="icon-' + weather.code + '"></i>' + weather.temp + '&deg;' + weather.units.temp + '</h2>';
            html += '<ul><li><i style="color:#000" class="icon-' + weather.code + '"></i>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</li>';
            html += '<li class="currently">' + weather.currently + '</li>';
            html += '<li>' + weather.alt.temp + '&deg;C</li></ul>';

            for (var i = 0; i < weather.forecast.length; i++) {
                img = '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="' + weather.forecast[i].image + '">';
                html += '<p>' + img + '<i style="color:#000" class="icon-' + weather.code + '"></i>' + weather.forecast[i].day + ': ' + weather.forecast[i].high + '</p>';
            }

            $("#weather").html(html);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjvnotza/)

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thanks heaps... I've been racking my brain all afternoon.